# A Isomorphism between the extension group and cohomology group of Lie algebras

Tags: lie-algebras, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology, lie-algebra-cohomology

Within the book *An introduction to homological algebra* by Weibel, I am trying to prove the following isomorphism, but I am not sure this is true. But I  really want to know how to prove or disprove it.

**Notation:**
Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a finite dimensional Lie algebra over a field.
Let $\text{H}^i_{\text{Lie}}(\mathfrak{g},A)$ be the i-th cohomology group of $\mathfrak{g} $ with the coefficients in the $\mathfrak{g}$-module $A$.

**Page 226:**
Let $M,N$ be $\mathfrak{g}$-modules. Then we have the following natural isomorphism of $\delta$ functors:

$$ \text{Ext}^\ast_{U \mathfrak{g}}(M,N) \cong \text{H}^\ast_{\text{Lie}}(\mathfrak{g}, \text{Hom}_{k}(M,N)) $$

where $\ast$ is a non-negative integer.

- I am thinking about the following possible way to prove this problem:

Both side are $\delta$-functor of $N$. Therefore it remains to show that
the $\text{H}^\ast_{\text{Lie}}(\mathfrak{g}, \text{Hom}_{k}(M,-))$ is a universal $\delta$-functor. For this, we have to show that it vanishes on injectives (and so effacable). I think that it is possible to show that if $Q$ is a injective $\mathfrak{g}$-module then $\text{Hom}_{k}(M,Q)$ is also a injective $\mathfrak{g}$-module. But I can not prove this.

Thanks very much!

Comment: Here $\text{Hom}_{k}(M,N) \cong M* \otimes N $ as $\mathfrak{g}$-modules.

Comment: Since $$\text{H}^\ast_{\text{Lie}}(\mathfrak{g}, \text{Hom}_{k}(M,N)) = \text{Ext}^\ast_{U(\mathfrak g)}(k, \text{Hom}_{k}(M,N)),$$ 
I guess that it would be sufficient to check that 
$$\mathrm{Hom}_{U(\mathfrak g)}(k, \mathrm{Hom}_k(M, N)) 
\cong 
\mathrm{Hom}_{U(\mathfrak g)}(k \otimes_k M, N) 
= \mathrm{Hom}_{U(\mathfrak g)}(M,N),$$ 
using the fact that this identity holds when 
$\mathrm{Hom}_{U(\mathfrak g)}(-,-)$ is replaced by $\mathrm{Hom}_k(-,-)$.